# How to delete user by email id using azure SCIM api in databricks?

Tags: powershell, api, databricks, azure-databricks, scim

I need to know if there is a way to delete a user from databricks using email only using SCIM api? As of now I can see it can only delete user by ID which means I need to first retrive the ID of the user and then use it to delete.

I am using this api from powershell to delete users by email.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the documentation for [Get Users command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-users#--get-users) of SCIM Users REST API, you can see that you can specify the filtering condition for it. For example, to find specific user, you can filter on the `userName` attribute, like this:

```
GET /api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users?filter=userName+eq+example@databricks.com  HTTP/1.1
Host: <databricks-instance>
Accept: application/scim+json
Authorization: Bearer dapi48…a6138b
```

it will return a list of items in the `Resources` section, from which you can extract user ID that you can use for delete operation:

```json
{
  "totalResults": 1,
  "startIndex": 1,
  "itemsPerPage": 1,
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
  ],
  "Resources": [
    {
      "id": "8679504224234906",
      "userName": "example@databricks.com",
      "emails": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "value": "example@databricks.com",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "entitlements": [
        {
          "value": "allow-cluster-create"
        },
        {
          "value": "databricks-sql-access"
        },
        {
          "value": "workspace-access"
        }
      ],
      "displayName": "User 1",
      "name": {
        "familyName": "User",
        "givenName": "1"
      },
      "externalId": "12413",
      "active": true,
      "groups": [
        {
          "display": "123",
          "type": "direct",
          "value": "13223",
          "$ref": "Groups/13223"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.I am  new to PS scripting.Let say I save the json output into a variable. How can I retreive only the ids into an array variable.

Comment: lets say for example I just want to store the id from the abaove json into a varibale. @Alex

Comment: I’m not PS expert, but could be something like this: `$id = $data.Resources[0].id` where data is result of execution of ConvertFrom-Json on the returned string